# Cambiar color de texto de una etiqueta pre al ser clickeada y devolverla al color original al dar click en otra, Angular 7

Tags: html5, angular, typescript, angular7

Estoy generando un **li** con un **ngFor** por cada experiencia de trabajo que agrega un usuario a un array y estoy usando una etiqueta **pre** para mostrar un texto respetando el formato con el que se guardo en caso de que se introdujeran saltos de linea, cree un método para cambiar el color del texto que está en esa etiqueta cuando se selecciona el **li** que le corresponde, en lo que necesito ayuda es en hacer que cuando se seleccione otro **li** diferente al **li** del **pre** que ya se modificó, vuelva a su color original que en este caso eso negro.

> Component.html

```
<li *ngFor="let xp of xpArray; index as i" id="li{{i}}"
    class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start"
    (click)="openForEditXP(xp); colorPre(i)" [class.active]="xp == selectedXp">
  <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
    <h5 class="mb-1">{{xp.empresa}}</h5>
    <small>De {{xp.fecha_inicio}} a {{xp.fecha_fin == '' ? 
           'Actualmente' : xp.fecha_fin}}</small>
  </div>
  <p class="mb-1">{{xp.puesto}}</p>
  <small class="mb-1">Jefe: {{xp.jefe}} | Tel: {{xp.tel_referencia}}</small>
  <div class="row">
    <p class="col-md-auto font-weight-bold pr-1">Proyectos:</p>
    <pre id="pre{{i}}" class="col pl-0 text-justify">{{xp.proyectos}}</pre>
  </div>
</li>
```

> Component.ts

```
colorPre(i: number) {
  if (document.getElementById('li'+i).style.background == "#FFFFFF") {
    document.getElementById('pre'+i).style.color = "#000";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('pre'+i).style.color = "#fff";
  }
}
```

Si no quedó muy clara mi explicación, les diré cómo debe funcionar, cuando yo le doy click a un **li**, ese se pinta de color negro ya que lo estoy seleccionando y con el método **colorPre(i);** cambio el color del texto de la etiqueta **pre** a blanco, ya que originalmente es negro y no se vería, pero cuando seleccione otro **li** diferente, el texto de la etiqueta **pre** anterior debe volverse negro otra vez y el de la etiqueta **pre** que pertenece al nuevo **li** seleccionado haga el mismo método de pintarse blanco el texto.

Comment: Lo mejor para poder hacer lo que quieres es que le asignes una clase especifica al li cuando le das click por ejemplo `active`, crea reglas css para la etiqueta `<pre>` que esta dentro del `li` que esté activo despues de hacer click. Y en el evento click lo primero que haces es buscar cualquier li que tenga la clase `active` y se la quitas, asi solo 1 estara activo a la vez

Comment: Ya se agrega la clase active en el li que selecciono con [class.active]="xp == selectedXp", ¿cómo podría asignarle el estilo al pre dentro del li activo sin que los otros se cambien igual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomando en cuenta la forma actual como lo estás poniéndole el color al pre, creo que eso simplemente podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
colorPre(i: number) {


  // No sé para qué verificas si el fondo del li es blanco.
  if (document.getElementById('li'+i).style.background == "#FFFFFF") {
    document.getElementById('pre'+i).style.color = "#000";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('pre'+i).style.color = "#fff";
  }

  // preActivoID sería un atributo o propiedad de tu componente no inicializado.

  // Verificas que preActivoID no sea null. (Porque en la primera vez será null)
  if ( preActivoID ) {
    // Si no es null, significa que ya le diste click a 1 LI anteriormente por lo menos.
    // Cambias el pre anterior a negro con ayuda del ID que se guardó antes.
    document.getElementById(preActivoID).style.color = '#000';
  }

  // Vuelves a guardar el id del nuevo pre que está activo..
  preActivoID = 'pre'+i;
}
```

Comment: Verifico si el fondo del li es blanco porque estaba pensando en usar ese mismo método para cambiarle el color al pre cuando se seleccionara otro li, pero logré realizarlo así, gracias por tu método, me funcionó

Answer (score 0):

Intenta agregarle al li el css [hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)

```
/* Selecciona cualquier elemento <li> cuando está "mantenido (hovered)" */
li:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
```